# How to record the stream of data (PixelPosition) dynamically?

Tags: image-processing, streams

I need to trace the moving of an object and get the coordinates of such movement. The set of coordinates will be used for the subsequent evaluation and analysis.
I can easy get the current real-time coordinates by use of the following expression:

```
Dynamic[ImageKeypoints[EdgeDetect[CurrentImage[], 30], "PixelPosition"]]
```

But I need to record all these coordinates in the list in the separate cell or in separate file. I need that this list contains an cumulative set of all coordinates, frame by frame.

Please, suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @rojo  "PixelPosition" is an argument of `ImageKeypoints`. One bracket was misplaced and was easily corrected.

Answer (score 10):

#### File Output

Use an [output stream](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html).

```
s = OpenWrite["your_filename"];

Dynamic[With[{a = ImageKeypoints[EdgeDetect[CurrentImage[], 30], "PixelPosition"]}, 
  Write[s, a]; a], Deinitialization :> Close[s]]
```

It will close the stream upon the deletion of the dynamic cell. It is not a bad idea to put time stamp with it.

```
Dynamic[With[{a = ImageKeypoints[EdgeDetect[CurrentImage[], 30], "PixelPosition"]}, 
      Write[s, AbsoluteTime[] -> a]; a], Deinitialization :> Close[s]]
```

#### Notebook Output

Use [`NotebookWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookWrite.html).

```
Dynamic[With[{a = ImageKeypoints[EdgeDetect[CurrentImage[], 30], "PixelPosition"]}, 
  NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[RawBoxes[ToBoxes[a]]]]; a],
  Initialization :> (nb = CreateDocument[, WindowTitle -> "PixelPosition"])]
```

#### Appending to List

Already answered by Mr. Sjoerd C. de Vries...

Answer (score 6):

```
pixpos = {};
Dynamic[
  a = EdgeDetect[CurrentImage[], 30]; 
  b = ImageKeypoints[a, "PixelPosition"]; 
  AppendTo[pixpos, b]; 
  a]
```

[image]

Let it run for some time then delete the graphic to stop the `Dynamic` and plot them to show we indeed collected the results:

```
Graphics@Table[{Hue[Random[]], Line[i]}, {i, pixpos}]
```

[image]